# how can i make an operator delete itself when executed?

Tags: python, operator

i have this script here. im trying to make the operator button remove itself from the n-panel once its clicked

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel
from bpy.types import Operator
#####
def build(self, context):
    temp_var=bpy
##### 
class op(Operator):
    bl_label="ok"
    bl_idname="create.operator"
    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({"INFO"},
            f"Compiled! Happy Editing!")
        return {'FINISHED'}
        build(self, context)
    
class Create(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = "Create Addon"
    bl_category = 'Create Addon'
    
    def draw (self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        row = col.row()
        create=col.operator(op.bl_idname, text="Build Addon!", icon='MODIFIER')
       

        
classes=[op, Create,]
def register():
    
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)
def unregister():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

build() is just temporary. later, it will build the addon with all the properties it needs once the operator is clicked which i think i have under control. all i need to know is how to make the operator button delete itself.

Comment: why don't you just use an if statement for the col.operator statement? something like if already_built: col_operator...and in the execute function, just just set already_built to True

Comment: im not sure how to format that exactly. could you write it in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import bpy

executed = False

def main(context):
    
    global executed
    
    context.active_object.scale.y = context.active_object.scale.y * 2
    executed = True


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Active object is: " + obj.name)
        row = layout.row()

        row.prop(obj, "name")


        if not executed:
            row = layout.row()
            row.operator("object.simple_operator")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

result:

[image]

Explanation:

I used a global variable (executed). I set it to True, if you press the button. At start it is False. In the draw function i only show the button (row.operator) if not executed (executed == False)

Comment: For demonstration purposes I guess it's fine to use global variables in this case but it's best to avoid them whenever unnecessary :) http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad I wonder though if it is possible without global variables?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie: for sure!